# Pattern matching issue in Angular 14 regex validator

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, validation

I am having an issue with pattern matching validation in angular 14. I have a dynamic text component that can support multiple different types of text input and custom pattern validation can be appended if need be.
Here is the setup of a text box for `type=monetary`

```
        case InputType.Monetary:
          response.icon = response.icon ?? 'attach_money-outlined';
          response.iconPosition = response.iconPosition ?? LayoutPositions.Left;
          response.placeholder = response.placeholder ?? '0.00';
          response.validationPattern = response.validationPattern ?? /^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|(\d+))(.\d{2})?$/gm;
          response.patternErrorText = response.patternErrorText ?? 'Please enter a valid dollar amount';
          response.mask = response.mask ?? this.currencyInputMask;
          break;
```

And here is how it is being applied

```
      if (response?.validationPattern) {
        this.form.get(response.responseId)?.setValidators(Validators.pattern(response.validationPattern));
      }
```

The issue I am facing is that when there is an **Even** number of characters in this text field it is showing invalid no matter what. And when there is an **Odd** number of characters in the text field it seems to be working as expected. I have vetted out the regex and I don't believe that is the issue. Attached are some screenshots of the issue

[Invalid State UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtsr9.png)

[Invalid State Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TviQ0.png)

[Valid State UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioUhu.png)

[Valid State Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsAvp.png)

I have tried

- alternate regex patterns
- regex as a string instead of as a RegEx type
- applying the regex directly instead of storing in a variable

Comment: Your regex pattern at least can be fixed:  [`^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/4XhuFp/1) further do you really need the `m` (multiline) and the `g` (global) flag for validation? Try without those.

Comment: Thank you! it turns out it was the `m`. You are right, I didn't need it and it was more of a remnant of somewhere else in my code. I am surprised it caused this behavior none-the-less. However, thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!

Comment: Pretty sure the multi-line property has nothing to do with it. https://regex101.com/r/qMPGpI/1 . However if your text box has the multi-line property in creation it will accept the newline char. If you've given the regex the global property, the validation might pertain to only the last match. I would check these conflicts before claiming that this or that fixed it.
Also your regex matches `11,111p66` https://regex101.com/r/1f681u/1

Answer (score 0):

[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) was able to solve this for me. The issue was the addition of the `m` (multiline) at the end of my regex. removing it solved the issue.